# c# delegate: Do i use this correctly?

Tags: c#, delegates

This is my first time using delegate in c# application. can some one check if i use  this correctly.

```
int totalsales = 0;

adddata(){ 
........ 
BeginInvoke(new UpdateSalesDelegate(UpdateSales), numbersale);

}

private delegate void UpdateSalesDelegate(int  args);

private void UpdateSales(int args){ 
totalsales = totalsales + args; 
Label.Text = "Total Sales: " + totalsales.ToString();

}
```

or should i use

```
    adddata(){ 
    ........ 
    BeginInvoke(new UpdateSalesDelegate(UpdateSales), new int numbersale);

    }
.................
```

which way is correct ?

Comment: Shouldn't UpdateSales use the passes on argument "args"?

Comment: new int? Fee-fi-fo-fum... I smell the blood of a java programmer!

Comment: thanks fixed, which one is correct ?
BeginInvoke(new UpdateSalesDelegate(UpdateSales), numbersale);
or BeginInvoke(new UpdateSalesDelegate(UpdateSales), new int numbersale);

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'd just use

```
BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    UpdateSales(numbersale);
});
```

That way:

- no need to declare a delegate type
- static type checking
- MethodInvoker has special detection/handling, so is slightly faster ( not much)

It also isn't clear what the async method will do; adding two numbers is overkill, fir example. You may need to consider thread safety and thread affinity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegate. This saves you from having to specify your own delegate each time.

```
void AddData()
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(UpdateSales), numbersale);
}    

void UpdateSales(int args)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Label.Text = "Total Sales: " + totalsales.ToString();
```

This code will most likely fail, since `BeginInvoke()` invokes the delegate asynchronously on a new thread and updating properties on the Label needs to be done on the UI thread.